# Font Awesome icons displaying differently on mobile view in header button

Tags: icons, font-awesome, pseudo-element

Apologies, total noob (self-taught). Have added a Font Awesome icon (fa fa-phone-alt) to button in header which is displaying correctly on desktop view, but with mobile view it's showing both the fa fa-phone and fa fa-phone-alt icons (2 x phones, facing different directions) and has added the word 'call' as well. How do I correct this so it only displays the 1 phone and no word 'call'?

[mobile view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IvA4t.jpg)
[desktop view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKkwY.png)

I've tried clearing cache, viewing in incognito mode, deleting and re-typing the code manually, changing from fa to fas, inspected and can see there's some 'before' and 'after' css (pseudo-elements?) creating the issue but I'm at a loss as to what to do next, especially when it's only showing on mobile view.

It's a wordpress site and I can also see that it's using 'all.css' for Font Awesome 5.14.0 (which when scrolling through existing questions was something that was mentioned).

Thanks for your patience while I'm learning!!

UPDATE:

I used the Custom HTML option and wrote the following code to build the button in the Header Widget:

```
<a class="button2" title="Call Now" href=" tel: 07 3497 4920"><i class="fa fa-phone-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i> 07 3497 4920</a>
```

And to colour the button I added the following code in the 'Additional CSS' box :

```
.button2, .site .wp-block-button .wp-block-button__link, input[type=submit] { display: inline-block; padding: 0.6em 1.7em; font-size: inherit; border-radius: 2px; font-weight: normal; letter-spacing: 0.03em; border-width: 2px; }


.site
.button2:not(:hover):not(:active):not(.has-background), .site .wp-block-button:not(.is-style-outline) .wp-block-button__link:not(:hover):not(:active):not(.has-background), .site input[type=submit]:not(:hover):not(:active):not(.has-background) { border-color: #2E3E60; background-color: #2E3E60; color: #fff; }


.button2:hover, .site .button:focus, .site .wp-block-button:not(.is-style-outline) .wp-block-button__link:hover, .site .wp-block-button:not(.is-style-outline) .wp-block-button__link:focus, .site input[type=submit]:hover, .site input[type=submit]:focus { background-color: #5A9F88 !important; border-color: #5A9F88 !important; color: #fff !important; }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, some WordPress themes give you options to display differently in mobile and desktop views so you can check that.

Secondly, can you provide more details, and if possible can you show a code snippet or share a snapshot of the code or the configuration you have made for the button?

Update:

You can keep some default color and styles using wordpress Styles option.

And for giving hover effect you can add below code in Additional CSS.

```css
.wp-block-button.button2 .wp-block-button__link:hover,
.wp-block-button.button2 .wp-block-button__link:active,
.wp-block-button.button2 .wp-block-button__link:focus {
    background: #5A9F88 !important;
    color: #fff !important;
    border-color: #5A9F88 !important;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I have added some code which I'm hoping helps!

Comment: Hey, I'm trying to regenerate the same at my end. Could you please tell me what WordPress theme are you using?

Comment: Thank you. It's a child theme of Twenty Twenty-One.

Comment: Ok, I've been troubleshooting and the problem does not exist if I convert the <a class back to "button" vs "button2" (which was my clumsy attempt to create a separate CSS class). 

So, if you have a simple way for me to change the colour of a button to override the existing CSS, that would definitely solve the issue.

Comment: Umm, you can simplify your approach and use default WordPress feature to create your desired button. Let me edit my answer and show you some way.